# Django Messages + Pinax

Tags: django

I get this error when I try to install pinax notifications together with django messages:

```
django_messages.Message.sender: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Message.sender' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Message.sender'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Message.sender' or 'Message.sender'.
django_messages.Message.sender: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Message.sender' clashes with reverse query name for 'Message.sender'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Message.sender' or 'Message.sender'.
pinax_messages.Message.sender: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Message.sender' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Message.sender'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Message.sender' or 'Message.sender'.
pinax_messages.Message.sender: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Message.sender' clashes with reverse query name for 'Message.sender'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Message.sender' or 'Message.sender'.
```

---

Where can I change the fields?

Thank you

Comment: The `sender` field of the `Message` model of django_messages is a `ForeignKey` to the user model, which probably sets `related_name` to "messages" (so that you can do `user.messages`). That clashes with the `sender` field of `Message` model in pinax that does the same. You'll need to either consider not using one of the two packages (aren't they providing similar functionality) or include one of them inside your own code (instead of pip install) and change the `related_name` inside the models.py.

Comment: So I'd need to clone the pinax project into a new app inside my project and change the model? Thats it?

Comment: Yes. But again, maybe you only want part of pinax (it consists of multiple apps, you may not need all) since I believe pinax-messages provides the same functionality as Django-messages. Why do you need two apps that provide user-to-user messages?

Comment: Maybe not, but good to know. Thank you